# Most efficient way to create this bevel profile?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I don't know what this specific kind of bevel is called. If someone does, please edit it in.

Essentially, I am trying to figure out how to create a bevel with a cusp on only one side.

[image]

In the case below, I am creating two such bevels, each with a cusp on one side, and such that the offset closes the entire distant between the two. In other words, the bevel offset = the width of the 'plank'.

[image]

I am also not necessarily looking for a method that arrives exclusively at 45° sections of a circle. 60° or 30° arcs before coming to a cusp would ideally also be nice.